# NativeScript Angular vs ts/xml

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

Which one should I choose for my new Mobile App project?

- NativeScript with Angular or
- NativeScript with ts/XML?

What are pros and cons?

Comment: My opinion is that you should use Angular.

Comment: Framework is a tool that you can leverage to develop large applications. If you are developing a helloworld app then  ts/XML should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with frameworks like Angular / Vue Or at least willing to learn if your project timeline allows, you should go with one of the framework for the features set it offers out of the box.

If you are feeling very much comfortable at JS / TS, then you are good with NativeScript Core itself. End of the day all your code is just JavaScript and there is nothing like one could be done only with Angular / Vue.

The choice purely depends on,

1. Your comfort level with the framework
2. Whether your project relies on any crucial feature offered by the framework
3. Is it possible to handle everything on your own rather spending time in learning a whole new framework?

Comment: Simple HelloWorld app bundle size is >100 mb if i go with Angular whereas core is <20 mb. This caused a confusion for me to choose. I am familiar with Angular.

Comment: That's is not exactly true, I have a few Angular apps with bundle size ranging between 18-22mb. You must be missing something in your compilation process, the bundle size may differ max by 1 or 2 mb between Angular and Core.